# Renaming pandas columns by slicing, causing merge to fail

Tags: python, pandas, merge

I've got two data frames that represent similar data but I want to merge after changing the col names. There are a few ways to achieve this but given the size of my actual data frames, I'd like to use the following method. I'm returning nan values for the second df.

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({
    'time': ['2012-08-02 09:50:20.0','2012-08-02 09:50:32.5','2012-08-02 09:50:34.8'],  
    'Val': ['1,2,3','1,2,3','1,2,3'],
    'Val2': [1,2,3],
    'Val3': [1.1,2.1,3.1]    
    })

df2 = pd.DataFrame({
    'time': ['2012-08-02 09:50:20.0','2012-08-02 09:50:32.5','2012-08-02 09:50:34.8'],
    'Val': ['1,2,3','1,2,3','1,2,3'],
    'Val2': [1,2,3],
    'Val3': [1.1,2.1,3.1]
    })

df1['time'] = pd.to_datetime(df1['time'])
df2['time'] = pd.to_datetime(df2['time'])

df1.columns.values[1:4] = ['first_' + str(x) for x in df1.columns[1:4]]
df2.columns.values[1:4] = ['second_' + str(x) for x in df2.columns[1:4]]

df3 = pd.merge(df1, df2, on = 'time')

print(df3)

                     time first_Val  first_Val2  first_Val3  second_Val  second_Val2  second_Val3
0 2012-08-02 09:50:20.000     1,2,3           1         1.1         NaN          NaN          NaN
1 2012-08-02 09:50:32.500     1,2,3           2         2.1         NaN          NaN          NaN
2 2012-08-02 09:50:34.800     1,2,3           3         3.1         NaN          NaN          NaN
```

Intended output:

```
                      time first_Val  first_Val2  first_Val3 second_Val  second_Val2  second_Val3
0  2012-08-02 09:50:20.000     1,2,3           1         1.1      1,2,3            1          1.1
1  2012-08-02 09:50:32.500     1,2,3           2         2.1      1,2,3            2          2.1
2  2012-08-02 09:50:34.800     1,2,3           3         3.1      1,2,3            3          3.1
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- The issue is slice assignment of the column names.

  - `df1.columns.values[1:4] = new values`
  - Fails in pandas 1.1.1 and 1.1.2
  - Works in 1.0.1 and 1.0.5
- `'time'` is set as the index, then reset, after changing the column names in a list-comprehension.

  - This demonstrates, it's okay to rename the columns with a list comprehension, but not by slicing `df.columns`.
- `.reset_index()` can be removed, to leave `'time'` as the index, in which case, use `df.join`, instead of `pd.merge`.
- The options are to set the column, which won't have a new name, as the index, or use `.rename` for the specific columns.

```py
df1 = pd.DataFrame({
    'time': ['2012-08-02 09:50:20.0','2012-08-02 09:50:32.5','2012-08-02 09:50:34.8'],  
    'first_Val': ['1,2,3','1,2,3','1,2,3'],
    'first_Val2': [1,2,3],
    'first_Val3': [1.1,2.1,3.1]    
    })
df1['time'] = pd.to_datetime(df1['time'])
df1.set_index('time', inplace=True)
df1.columns = ['first_' + str(x) for x in df1.columns]
df1.reset_index(inplace=True)

df2 = pd.DataFrame({
    'time': ['2012-08-02 09:50:20.0','2012-08-02 09:50:32.5','2012-08-02 09:50:34.8'],
    'Val': ['1,2,3','1,2,3','1,2,3'],
    'Val2': [1,2,3],
    'Val3': [1.1,2.1,3.1]
    })
df2['time'] = pd.to_datetime(df2['time'])
df2.set_index('time', inplace=True)
df2.columns = ['second_' + str(x) for x in df2.columns]
df2.reset_index(inplace=True)

# merge
df3 = pd.merge(df1, df2, on = 'time', how='left')

                     time first_first_Val  first_first_Val2  first_first_Val3 second_Val  second_Val2  second_Val3
0 2012-08-02 09:50:20.000           1,2,3                 1               1.1      1,2,3            1          1.1
1 2012-08-02 09:50:32.500           1,2,3                 2               2.1      1,2,3            2          2.1
2 2012-08-02 09:50:34.800           1,2,3                 3               3.1      1,2,3            3          3.1
```

Answer (score 2):

Okay, let's try this a different way:

```
df1 = df1.set_index('time').add_prefix('first_')
df2 = df2.set_index('time').add_prefix('second_')

df3 = pd.merge(df1, df2, on = 'time')

print(df3)
```